# Is there an option to retrieve all unique sessions using Google's Core Reporting API?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm wondering if there's a possibility to fetch disaggregated data from Google, using their APIs.
Currently I'm able to already receive a quite detailed segmentation by selecting `ga:source`, `ga:dateHourMinute`, `ga:country` and others, but of course these are still groups of sessions.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not by default - there is no dimensions for sessions in the API, and not even the client id is exposed via the API.

An easy way to obtain a session marker is to store a random number in a session scoped custom dimension. Since a session scoped dimension by definition stores only the last value in the session this will give you an unique (well, not technically unique, but unique enough) value per session, which can be use in conjunction with the client id, which you'd need to store in another custom dimension.

Of course since this will give you a lot of single rows you will be running into API limits pretty soon.

In a GA360 account you could use BigQuery - the BQ export schema includes session identifiers.